# Multidimensional Table

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to create a multidimensional table without certain indices. For example, I would like to write

T:=Table[x, {i,1,10}, {j,1,10}]

with i!=j.

Is there any command that I can add into Table to impose i different from j?

Thanks!

Comment: "any command ... to impose i different from j?" - `If[]`?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what you're asking, but I would suspect something like `Table[If[i!=j, x, Nothing], {i,1,10}, {j,1,10}]` may do the trick.

Comment: Of course!! Thank you!!!